# HBase UI doesn't show any region servers

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I run hbase in a distributed mode. Hbase starts region servers java processes on all nodes, but web ui doesn' show them

http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20120517/16DXTnsU.png

here is hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>10.3.6.44</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/hadoop/hdfs/zookeeper</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
     <value>hdfs://10.3.6.44:9000/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

btw hadoop cluster is running normally and sees all the datanodes

---

thanks very much for your help.
problem was with dns and hosts file.

Comment: In region servers logs there is an error: Unable to connect to Master Server at localhost, 60000...   Why they're trying to connecto to localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Add this property to your hbase-site.xml file and see if it works for you

```
  name - hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort
  value - 2181
```

Comment: also add these properties -> hbase.master:hostname:60000 and hbase.regionserver.port:60020

Comment: did not help:( how its possible region servers try to connect with master using localhost and not 10.3.6.44

Comment: seems like hosts file problem

Comment: Which version of hadoop and hbase are you using??Please add hadoop-core-*.jar from your HADOOP_HOME and commons-collections-3.2.1.jar from your HADOOP_HOME/lib directory into your HBASE_HOME/lib directory..sometimes it happens because of version incompatibility between hadoop and hbase.

Comment: thanks very much for your help. problem was with dns and hosts file.

Comment: great..could you share the problem and the solution??

Comment: On master machine in hosts file was a line [current-machine-hostname] 127.0.0.1, just removed it. After that region servers used correct master server hostname to connect